# How to limit creation of documents with same parent reference

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**Explanation**

I am making a vpn app, and I'm trying to model the order with the plans. Each order has a virtual field array of plans. When a plan is created, it must reference an order so that the populate works. I know I can limit the amount of plans shown when I populate, but I want to limit the amount of plans **created** for each order to stop spam. So if the limit is 10 plans, if someone tries to create an 11th plan with the same order reference, it will throw an error.

**sample**:

1. User creates and order with ID: 1
2. User creates 10 plans with the order id:1
3. The order has 10 plans associated with it
4. User tries to create another plan with order id:1, but fails

Here is my **orderSchema**:

```
const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
      required: [true, "Please provide a user for this order"],
    },
    //... other fields
  }
);

// This is the array of plans connected to this order
orderSchema.virtual("plans", {
  foreignField: "order",
  localField: "_id",
  ref: "Plan",

});
```

Here is my **planSchema**:

```
const planSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      required: [true, "Please provide a user for this plan"],
      ref: "User",
    },
    order: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      required: [true, "Please provide an order to process this plan"],
      ref: "Order",
    },
    type: {
      type: String,
      enum: {
        values: ["oneMonth", "sixMonth", "oneYear"],
        message: "Plan type must be one of the following: 'oneMonth', 'sixMonth', 'oneYear'",
      },
      required: [true, "Please provide the type of plan"],
    },
    //... other fields
  }
);
```

**Extra thoughts**:
Could there be some sort of index that limits the order field to have 10 of the same ones? If not, totally fine, I just need a solution to this, thanks.

Comment: could you provide some sample

Comment: I just added it

Comment: you want implement with node.js or mongodb ?

Comment: nodejs and mongoose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

before adding new plan to order you should send query to `plan` collection
to find number of plan with orderId and userId if the number is less than 10
add new plan
1 - query to find user and orderId
2 - if number of plans is less than 10 create else return false

```
app.post('/create',(req,res)=>{
var numberOfPlans = await plans.find({user:userId,order:orderId}).countDocuments()
if (numberOfPlans < 10) {
   plans.create({data})
   res.json({status:true})
}
else {
res.json({status:false})
}
})
```

Comment: I see how this could work, but wouldn't it cause performance issues since every time you create something, it sends two requests?

Comment: so add new schema for collecting `userId`, 'numberOforderPlans` , this is so faster

Comment: I see. I'll try it out.

Comment: It works, but I still don't like the idea of querying twice. If there isn't any better answer by the end of the day, I will mark this as the answer. Thanks!